# how to source with sudo -u

Tags: bash, redhat, sudo

Redhat Linux using Bash

1. I login in as myself
2. sudo to another user

sudo -u  bash

I want to call a bash_profile when I do this. When I run this, I get the following error

bash: /home/myuser/.bashrc: Permission denied

Myuser: the username that I log in with.

Comment: Try `sudo -i -u username`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo -i -u username
```

should trigger the login shell for that user, as suggested above, and pick up all their .whatever preferences.

Alternatively, I'm more in the habit of doing this:

```
sudo su - username
```